# Tensorflow giving same output for different input, how to fix that?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence

i am working on vectorial prediction. I have a input vector with a specific size and i want to predict the output vector with a smaller size. For example, a vector with 80 numbers predicts a vector with 8 numbers. When i train my model and try predicting it, it will always output the same result for a different input, here is my method:

```
def create_neural_net_and_feed_it(X_train : np.array,  X_test : np.array, Y_train : np.array, Y_test : np.array, vector_size):
   stock_amount = X_train.shape[0]
   data_length = X_train.shape[1]   
   dropout_rate = 0.3


   layer_size = 6
   layer_number = 6



   early_stopping_callback = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=30, restore_best_weights=True)


   model = keras.Sequential()


   model.add(Dense(units = data_length, input_dim = data_length))

   for i in range(0, layer_number):
       model.add(Dense(units = layer_size, activation='sigmoid'))
       model.add(Dropout(rate = dropout_rate))

   model.add(Dense(units = vector_size))


   model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

   history = model.fit(x=X_train, y=Y_train, batch_size=1, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), epochs=100, callbacks=[early_stopping_callback])

   figure, axis = plt.subplots(5, 2)
   my_predictions = []


   for i in range(0, Y_test.shape[0]):
       print(Y_test[i])
       print("-----------------------------------")
       X_test_reshaped_line = np.reshape(a=X_test[i], newshape=(1, X_test[i].shape[0]))
       my_pred = model.predict(X_test_reshaped_line)
       my_predictions.append(my_pred)
       print(my_pred)

       axis[i, 0].plot(Y_test[i])
       axis[i, 0].set_title("Test-set values")
    
       axis[i, 1].plot(my_predictions[i][0])
       axis[i, 1].set_title("Predicted values")

        print("############################################\n############################################")

   plt.show()
```

When i try to predict single vectors with that, i get an output like that (only partial output):

```
Output as it should look like: 
[147.71  147.05  146.83  144.38  148.045 153.785 153.7   152.81 ]
-----------------------------------
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 87ms/step
Prediction:
[[95.124146 95.21927  95.3641   95.4432   95.540924 95.65227  95.67437
  95.795525]]
############################################
############################################
Output as it should look like:
[147.05  146.83  144.38  148.045 153.785 153.7   152.81  153.559]
-----------------------------------
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step
Prediction:
[[95.124146 95.21927  95.3641   95.4432   95.540924 95.65227  95.67437
   95.795525]]
############################################
############################################
Output as it should look like:
[146.83  144.38  148.045 153.785 153.7   152.81  153.559 150.21 ]
-----------------------------------
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step
Prediction:
[[95.124146 95.21927  95.3641   95.4432   95.540924 95.65227  95.67437
  95.795525]]
```

As you can see, my prediction is ALWAYS the same. The train and test data split is correct, i looked over it multiple times, so this cannot be the problem.

Here is what i tried:
Normalization - not working.
Different NN size (hidden layers and neurons amount) - not working.
Googleing it: Some people had similar problems, but nothing worked for me.

Comment: What do you notice during training? Does the model improve over time, or also stuck like that?

Comment: Try using relu activation instead of sigmoid for the hidden layers.

Comment: @ShivamSingh i tried, it changed nothing.

Comment: @FelixFourcolor the model improves up to a given threshhold, then it gets stuck and the early-stop callback stops training.

Comment: Uncleaned data is also a reason for the error you are getting. If your dataset has some negative values then the activation functions might kill the information learned by the model. For example in case of relu it clips neg values so it only majorly learns distribution for datarows that has positive features. My suggestion try leaky_relu as activation function or lower the learning rate or instead of mse try using mae for loss function.

Comment: I agree with @ShivamSingh, it's probably bad data. Also try changing batch size, as 1 is abnormally small.

If you don't mind posting the data, I will play with it to see what I can do.

Comment: @ShivamSingh+FelixFourcolor the data is stock data, so there are no negatives. The program tries predicting stock data from a set of given stocks (Microsoft, Apple etc.). One observation contains as many time steps from the specific stock as the parameter vector_size says. For example, if vector_size = 8 and i have ten specific stocks, i have 80 data points in one observation. From that, i extract one specific stock and try to predcit its 8 values with the other 72 data points.

Comment: @Felix Here is my dataset: fileport.io/N4zHtFN4h1Cg

Comment: Try using lstm layers instead of dense. Typically dense layers could learn linear relationships which in your case is not what you want since the next day stock price might depend on previous 7 days data. The dense layer cannot learn this timeseries relation. Try LSTM or RNN.

Comment: @ShivamSingh i did, but does not make any difference. The thing is, i accumulate the single time steps into a vector, the Dense layer accepts many time steps, so there is no need of recognition (like LSTM layers do), because it already accepts a "time-frame".

Comment: @FelixFourcolor i think i did the "mentionin a name"-thing wrong, but here is it :). I packed the dataset you requested into the link you can see in the comments above.

Comment: @Animalz I saw the earlier message, I haven't had time though. When I asked for the data, I was hoping you'd include the code that reads from the data as well (basically the whole runnning package), rather than the description that you sent, which was a bit confusing. Don't worry about if it's incovenient for you though, I don't promise that I will have time to look into it, let alone be able to help anything.

Comment: @ShivamSingh It's not possible that this is a matter of model design (dense/RNN/LSTM layer or relu/sigmoid activation ). A six-layer dense model is well-capable to learn *anything*, even random noise. Since OP unconventionally (mistakenly?) monitored the loss rather than validation loss, the early stopping triggered means the model even failed to learn the data it was trained on. This is not normal, I suspect there's a systemic issue with the data.

Comment: @FelixFourcolor i posted my entire code below.

Answer (score 0):

@Felix Fourcolor, here is my entire code:

```
import datetime as dt
import urllib.request
import json
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
import keras
import sys
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
from UsefulFunctions import HistoryPlotter as HP

os.environ["KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK"]="TRUE"


def main():
    np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
    begin = dt.date(2022, 12, 10)
    end = dt.date(2023, 2, 10)
    vector_size = 8
    normalize_flag = False

  
    ticker_symbols = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'AMZN', 'ADBE','AAT','AAU', 'AB','ABBV','ABC','ABCB']
    #ticker_symbols = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'AMZN', 'ADBE', 'AAT']
    pair_list = create_key_val_pair(ticker_symbols)

    #actualize_files(ticker_symbols, pair_list)
    [morning_numpy_array, evening_numpy_array] = read_files(ticker_symbols, begin, end)
    sequenced_dataset_morning = create_sequence_dataset(morning_numpy_array, vector_size, normalize_flag)
    sequenced_dataset_evening = create_sequence_dataset(evening_numpy_array, vector_size, normalize_flag)
    
    
    
    [X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test] = create_train_test_split(sequenced_dataset_morning, ticker_symbols)
    [X_train, X_test] = reshape_data_for_nn(X_train, X_test, normalize_flag)
    create_neural_net_and_feed_it_yummy_yummy(X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test, vector_size)





def create_neural_net_and_feed_it_yummy_yummy(X_train : np.array,  X_test : np.array, Y_train : np.array, Y_test : np.array, vector_size):
    stock_amount = X_train.shape[0]
    data_length = X_train.shape[1]   
    dropout_rate = 0.3
    #log_base = 2
    
    layer_size = 6
    layer_number = 6

    
    early_stopping_callback = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=30, restore_best_weights=True)
    

    model = keras.Sequential()


    model.add(Dense(units = data_length, input_dim = data_length))
    
    for i in range(0, layer_number):
        model.add(Dense(units = layer_size, activation='sigmoid'))
        model.add(Dropout(rate = dropout_rate))
    
    model.add(Dense(units = vector_size))

    
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='sgd', metrics='mean_absolute_error')
    
    history = model.fit(x=X_train, y=Y_train, batch_size=1, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), epochs=200, callbacks=[early_stopping_callback])

    figure, axis = plt.subplots(5, 2)
    my_predictions = []
    
    
    for i in range(0, Y_test.shape[0]):
        #print("Output as it should look like: ")
        #print(Y_test[i])
        #print("-----------------------------------")
        X_test_reshaped_line = np.reshape(a=X_test[i], newshape=(1, X_test[i].shape[0]))

        print("X_test[i] shape: ")
        print(X_test_reshaped_line.shape)
        print("-----------------------------")
        my_pred = model.predict(X_test_reshaped_line)
        my_predictions.append(my_pred)
        print("Prediction: ")
        print(my_pred.shape)

        axis[i, 0].plot(Y_test[i])
        axis[i, 0].set_title("Test-set values")
        
        axis[i, 1].plot(my_predictions[i][0])
        axis[i, 1].set_title("Predicted values")

        print("############################################\n############################################")

    plt.show()



def reshape_data_for_nn(X_train : np.array, X_test : np.array, normalize_flag):

    if normalize_flag:
        X_train = np.reshape(a=X_train, newshape=(X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1]*X_train.shape[3]))
        X_test = np.reshape(a=X_test, newshape=(X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1]*X_test.shape[3]))
    else:
        X_train = np.reshape(a=X_train, newshape=(X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1]*X_train.shape[2]))
        X_test = np.reshape(a=X_test, newshape=(X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1]*X_test.shape[2]))
    
    return [X_train, X_test]
    


def create_train_test_split(numpy_dataset : np.array, ticker_symbols : list):  
    split_var = -5
    target : np.array = numpy_dataset[:, 0, :]
    input : np.array = numpy_dataset[:, 1:, :]
    
    
    Y_train = target[:split_var]
    Y_test = target[target.shape[0] + split_var : target.shape[0]]

    #for i in range(0, input.shape[0]):
        #temp_list_train.append(input[i][:split_var])
        #temp_list_test.append(input[i][input.shape[0] + split_var : input.shape[0]]) 

    X_train = input[:split_var, :, :]
    X_test = input[input.shape[0] + split_var : input.shape[0], :, :]
    

    return [X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test]

    



def create_sequence_dataset(numpy_array : np.array, seq_length : int, normalize_flag):
    sequence_list = []
    big_sequence_list = []
    
    
    for i in range(0, numpy_array.shape[0]-seq_length):

        for j in range(0, numpy_array.shape[1]):
            temp = numpy_array[i : i+seq_length, j]

            if(normalize_flag):
                temp = normalize([temp])


            sequence_list.append(temp)
        
        
        
        big_sequence_list.append(np.array(sequence_list, dtype='float'))
        sequence_list = []

    return np.array(big_sequence_list)
        

    


def read_files(ticker_symbols, begin_date, end_date):
    delta = end_date-begin_date
    delta = delta.days
    
    counter = 0
    #morning_numpy_array = np.empty([len(ticker_symbols), int(delta)])
    #evening_numpy_array = np.empty([len(ticker_symbols), int(delta)])
    morning_numpy_array = []
    evening_numpy_array = []

    for item in ticker_symbols:
        file = open('C:/Users/Moritz/Desktop/Allgemeines/MachineLearning/mydata/'+str(item)+".txt").read()
        lines = file.split("\n")

        morning_list = []
        evening_list = []
        #morning_list.append(str(item))
        #evening_list.append(str(item))

        for line in lines:
            
            data = line.split(";")

            if data[0] == '' or data[1] == '' or data[2] == '':
                continue

            morning_list.append(data[1].replace(" ",""))
            evening_list.append(data[2].replace(" ",""))
        
        morning_numpy_array.append(np.array(morning_list))
        evening_numpy_array.append(np.array(evening_list))

        counter = counter + 1

    return [np.transpose(np.array(morning_numpy_array)), np.transpose(np.array(evening_numpy_array))]





def actualize_files(ticker_symbols, pair_list):
    #begin_date = get_last_date_from_files()
    begin_date = dt.date(2018, 4, 1)
    end_date = dt.date.today()
    #end_date = get_first_date_from_files()
    download_data_and_write_to_file(begin_date, end_date, ticker_symbols, pair_list)

def get_first_date_from_files():
    file = open('C:/Users/Moritz/Desktop/Allgemeines/MachineLearning/mydata/'+"AAU"+".txt").read()
    lines = file.split("\n")
    lines = lines[0].split(";")
    lines = lines[0].split("-")

    i0 = int(lines[0])
    i1 = int(lines[1])
    i2 = int(lines[2])
    temp = dt.date(i0, i1, i2)
    temp = temp + dt.timedelta(-1)

    return temp


def get_last_date_from_files():
    file = open('C:/Users/Moritz/Desktop/Allgemeines/MachineLearning/mydata/'+"AAU"+".txt").read()
    lines = file.split("\n")
    lines = lines[len(lines)-3].split(";")
    lines = lines[0].split("-")

    i0 = int(lines[0])
    i1 = int(lines[1])
    i2 = int(lines[2])
    temp = dt.date(i0, i1, i2)
    temp = temp + dt.timedelta(1)

    return temp

def download_data_and_write_to_file(begin, end, ticker_symbols, pair_list : dict):
    delta = end - begin
    downloaded_data = np.zeros(shape=[delta.days+1, len(ticker_symbols)])
    downloaded_data[0,:] = list(pair_list.keys())
    #counter = 0


    for item in ticker_symbols:
        dest = 'C:/Users/Moritz/Desktop/Allgemeines/MachineLearning/mydata/'+str(item)+".txt"
        temp = begin
        api_key = 'not interesting'

        while temp <= end:
            #counter = counter + 1
            try:
                if temp.weekday() != 6 and temp.weekday() != 5:

                    
                    
                    myUrl = 'https://api.polygon.io/v1/open-close/'+str(item)+'/'+str(temp)+'?adjusted=true&apiKey='+api_key
                    response = urllib.request.urlopen(myUrl)
                    response_as_string = response.read()
                    jsonObject = json.loads(response_as_string)

                    with open(dest, "a") as myfile:
                        myfile.write(str(temp)+"; "+str(jsonObject.get('open'))+"; "+str(jsonObject.get('close'))+"\r\n")        

                    print(str(temp)+" - "+str(item)+"; SUCCESSFULLY WRITTEN TO FILE")
                    


            except:
                pass
            
            #if counter == 5:
                #counter = 0
                #print("Sleeping")
                #time.sleep(70)

                

            temp = temp+dt.timedelta(1)


def create_key_val_pair(ticker_symbols):
    pair_list = {}
    counter = 0
    for item in ticker_symbols:
        pair_list[counter] = str(item)
        counter = counter + 1
    
    return pair_list



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```